# How to explain this question and answer on parametric equations from MIT 18.02?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a question from MIT's multi-variable course on parametric equations:

[image]

And this is the **answer**:
[image]

However, I'm not entirely sure how the answer was arrived. I started off tackling the question by letting P be the point $(1,1,1)$, and Q being a point anywhere on the plane $(x, y, z)$. Then $\vec{PQ} = (x-1, y-1, z-1)$. I assume $(a,b,c)$ is a direction vector such that:

$$\vec{PQ} = t(a,b,c)$$
$$(x-1, y-1, z-1) = t(a, b, c)$$

This is as far as I got..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your direction vector $(a,b,c)$ must be orthogonal to the plane $x+2y-z=2$, which requires $a+2b-c=0$, i.e $c=a+2b$

Second, your  $(x-1, y-1, z-1) = t(a, b, c) =(at,bt,ct)$ gives
$$x-1 = ta \text{ , i.e. } x=1+at$$
$$y-1 = tb \text{ , i.e. } y=1+bt$$
$$z-1 = tc \text{ , i.e. } z=1+ct = 1+(a+2b)t$$

so you get the same result as the model answer

Comment: I thought the vector $(1, 2, -1)$ is normal to the plane, so do you mean the direction vector must be parallel instead?

Comment: $(1,2,−1)$ is normal to the plane, so you need its dot product with a direction vector on the plane $(a,b,c)$ to be $0$.  That means $1a+2b - 1 c=0$.  Possible examples for $(a,b,c)$ include $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,2)$ and many others

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, one description of a plane $P$ is a point and a normal vector $\vec{n}$. Any vector $\vec{x}$ in $P$ must be orthogonal to $\vec{n}$, so if we denote the direction vector of $\vec{x}=\langle a,b,c\rangle$, we must have $\langle a,b,c\rangle\cdot \langle 1,2,-1\rangle =0$, or $a+2b-c=0$. We might as well write $c=a+2b$, which gives the direction vector as $\langle a,b,a+2b\rangle$ for any $a,b$. Requiring the vector to pass through $(1,1,1)$ gives $\langle 1+a,1+b,1+a+2b\rangle$.